# Memory test while booting . Unable to boot Ubuntu 12 04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. All of a sudden, my I'm unable to load the OS. A memory test is happening while I'm trying to boot the system.

Comment: Do you mean a RAM (memory) test or is it running a check of the disk (fsck)?

Comment: You probably made a keyboard mistake in the boot, and you selected `memtest86` to boot.

Comment: @slm Yes. Its not normal memory test. It dint happen just once. Now I am unable to boot the system. I am at the verge formatting my system. T_T

Comment: A re-install isn't guaranteed to make things better though. Can you get a picture of the monitor with the messages and post it?

Comment: It is memtest86+ v4.20 . The test keeps running. Never stopped. 
**[Please refer this image](http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6179/6149998253_2bdbf7337f_z.jpg)** . This is not the image of my computer. But this is exactly the case.

Comment: Please help. Still the problem persist.